# How to run the programe with parameters inside gdb?

Tags: gdb

Suppose I'm in `gdb memcached`,but want to run it as `memcached -d -u root -m 50 -c 1024 -p 11051`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the gdb prompt, juste type

> run -d -u root -m 50 -c 1024 -p 11051

Answer (score 1):

Alternativerly, you can also use the `args` parameter:

```
(gdb) help set args
Set argument list to give program being debugged when it is started.
Follow this command with any number of args, to be passed to the program.
```

so in your case:

```
set args -d -u root -m 50 -c 1024 -p 11051
run (or) start
```